# Tensorflow sess.run InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow.
I have this placeholder `x = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [in_len], name = "x")` in the Tensor model.
And I try to use the following comments to execute this Tensor model with input image `img_20_tf`

```
sess = tf.Session()
result_index = sess.run(model.eval(session=sess), feed_dict={x: img_20_tf})
```

I tried to check the shape and dtype for `img_20_tf` and it returns me `(3072,)` and `<dtype: 'float64'>`.
But still, I saw this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zhongyuyi/.conda/envs/Packaged program/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1356, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Users/zhongyuyi/.conda/envs/Packaged program/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1341, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/Users/zhongyuyi/.conda/envs/Packaged program/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1429, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype double and shape [3072]
     [[{{node x}}]]
```

I really don't see how there is mismatch between the data type and shape. Can anyone please help? Thanks a lot!